# capture user signature from client side - how to overcome security issues?

Tags: javascript, security, html5-canvas

I have a form (made in reactJS) and i need to ask for the users signature.
as far as i can tell all the solutions out there relay on the browser to produce what is essentially is a file in base64.
This poses a security issue for me since anyone can then on the client side give their own file instead of the generated one which could lead to uploading of viruses and such.
I do not have the option of passing it via an antivirus or other solutions like that.
Is there a way to validate it on the server side? or some whole different approached to this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for file validation server side without uploading file itself, this is not really possible literally, but one can think in some creative approaches to this, like `SHA 256` validation of base64 encoded file client-side using some related js library like [js-sha256](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha256):

1. Client-side: User signature file named signature.sig with following content:
   `SignatureFile1234567890`
2. Client-side: base64 encode of this file: `U2lnbmF0dXJlRmlsZTEyMzQ1Njc4OTA=`
3. Client-side: sha256 of above base64 string(generated using js-sha256):
   `2bdb56a39b4ea7f5831740e0d0b6d2b13a462e4ed5c9145594a6635e76562010`
4. Server-side: send to client sha256 hash of signature file stored on server
5. Client-side: Validate both hashes

Ofc, this is an integrity validation exposed to library specific vulnerabilities and chosen hash algorithm collisions, and you will make hash of the signature avaliable client-side.

Comment: its a good idea, but in fact since everything is on client side as you said its only integrity. the "hacker" can simply choose his own file before validation even starts and then all i will be validating is the file he picked. no?

Comment: Yeah, an attacker could forge his own files, but to find the correct one to match original file's hash will take 2ˆ256 attempts, the so called hash collision (using SHA-256).

Comment: but again, the original file is dynamicly created by the user as he generates his own signiture. so the hash value would be different everytime. am i missing somehting?

Comment: User should generate a new signature every time? If so, thats not a signature but a file acting as a kind of token, in this case server and client should agree in some seed data for the file to be verifiable. If the file will be generated just once, then hash will be same every time user uses it, ofc in this case that signature file should be uploaded to server for it to be verifiable. In both cases, hash utilization will avoid file uploading on every user interaction as you asked for.

Comment: can you give me an example on first scenario on how to achive this?